# Angular 6 authenticating to an IdentityServer 4 issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm working on an Angular 6 project that is authenticating to an IdentityServer 4, even though I'm logging in with the correct credentials and the correct login method, and then executing the "this.oidcSecurityService.authorize ()" method -auth-oidc-client " I get the message that the user is not authenticated. It's as if the "PasswordSignInAsync" did not work, even though it did not show error. Does anyone know what this can be?

Login Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true);                          
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName));                    
                return Ok();
            }
           ;

            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "Usuário ou senha inválidos"));

            ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
        }

        // something went wrong, show form with error
        var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
        return Ok(vm);
    }
```

[IdentityServer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtcY6.jpg)

[Browser Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5paqo.jpg)

Comment: I think you didn't exactly understand how SPA authentication works. For SPA you typically use the implicit flow to get an access token and pass that with every ajax query to the server. And your api and identity server are usually two separate applications then

Comment: @Tseng Thank you man.